# Search and compare string from ul li using python

Tags: list, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to search a string from the list using python (Selenium webdriver)

```
<li role="treeitem" aria-expanded="true" id="List" class="jstree-node  jstree-open">
   <i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
   <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Employees</a>
   <ul role="group" class="jstree-children">
      <li role="treeitem" id="workid:1" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
         <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Anna Def(1)</a></li>
      <li role="treeitem" id="workid:2" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf" aria-selected="false"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
          <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Dave Hjk(2)</a></li>
      <li role="treeitem" id="workid:3" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
          <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Ght Dgh(3)</a></li>
       <li role="treeitem" id="workid:4" class="jstree-node  jstree-leaf"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-ocl"></i>
          <a class="jstree-anchor" href="#"><i class="jstree-icon jstree-themeicon"></i>Acdc Dedef(4)</a></li>
```

From this list I want to find the Employee Dave Hjk(2)from the tree and select him. How can I search using loop?

This is what I tried but I think the way I'm getting the array (li) is worng :(

```
  li = SeleniumHelperInstance.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id="List"]/ul")


  for i in range(len(li)):
    selectuser = "Dave Hjk(2)"
    compUser = SeleniumHelperInstance.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#List > ul > li:nth-child(i)")
    if (selectuser == compUser.text):
        compUser.click()
```

Comment: what have you tried so far.. a small code snippet of what have you tried would be better to help you out.

Comment: @pArAs I updated with my code I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first locate the tree and then the link with `find_element_by_link_text` :

```
driver.find_element_by_id("List") \
      .find_element_by_link_text("Dave Hjk(2)") \
      .click()
```

You could also use an XPath to get the the link with a single call:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('List')//a[.='Dave Hjk(2)']") \
      .click()
```

Comment: This works. why do you need to find_element_by_id first, if we are using find_element_by_link_text? I didn't understand how it is doing the loop ?

Comment: You could directly call `find_element_by_link_text` but if there were multiple `Dave Hjk(2)` in the page, then you'd probably click the wrong one. The `find_element_by_id` ensure that the link is a child of the targeted list with id `List`.